# Facebook App Profile Page returning "The page you requested was not found."

Tags: profile, facebook-apps

When I create a new app and try to visit the app's profile page I get "The page you requested was not found."  This has been happening for the last 3 hours or so.  Existing apps work, it's just new ones.

Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not Facebook support. This site is for programmers asking programming questions. Anything having to do with Facebook administration or policies must be directed to Facebook.

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440277/is-facebook-removing-app-profile-page

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I was directed here through Facebook's developer site so I figured this was the right place.  

Seeing as I'm working on developing an app, but can't post it to a page as I can't access the app's profile page to test, I figured the developer support page was the place to come.  My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Open bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/325983410747148?browse=search_4ee22807295ec1d23119808